# How to merge two object data become one

Tags: angular, typescript

I two data need to merge become one. My example data like this..

**First data**

```
{Address: "Test", City: "test", State: "Test"}
```

**Second Data**

```
{UserId:"John", Name: "John"}
```

When I use this method `const a = [].concat(this.firstData, this.secondData);` it become in array not combine become one, example like bellow:

```
(2)[{…}, {…}]

[0]{Address: "Test", City: "test", State: "Test", …}
[1]{UserId:"John", Name: "John", …}
```

What method should I use to merge become one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the spread operator on both:

```js
const firstData = {Address: "Test", City: "test", State: "Test"};
const secondData = {UserId:"John", Name: "John"};

const merged = { ...firstData, ...secondData };

console.log(merged)
```

Useful references:

- [Docs for Variable Declarations/Spread in TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#spread).
- [Docs for JavaScript's Spread Operator (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.assign` which copies all enumerable properties from one or several objects into a target object. It returns the target object.

```
var x = { name: 'Jhon', last: 'Lennon' };
var y = { bday: new Date('1940-10-09') };
var z = Object.assign({}, x, y);

console.log(z);

// Output:
// { name: 'Jhon', last: 'Lennon', bday: 1940-10-09T00:00:00.000Z }
```

> More about `Object.assign` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign